# Finding common "subchains" within 2 vectors

Tags: r, permutation, combinations, combinatorics

I have an odd problem that I'm trying to solve in R:
Let's say we have 2 vectors, x and y, where every element within each vector is unique, the vectors have the same length, and vector 2 is a permutation of vector 1:

```
x <- LETTERS[c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)]
y <- LETTERS[c(5,8,7,9,6,10,1,3,2,4)]
```

Lets define a "chain" as a special type of permutation, with a defined first and last element.
e.g. a permutation of `"A" "B" "C" "D"` might be `"C" "B" "D" "A"`
while a "chain" of `"A" "B" "C" "D"` might be `"A" "C" "B" "D"`

My goal is to identify all the "chains" x and y have in common.  For example, x and y have a chain of length 4 in common:

```
> x[1:4]
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
> y[7:10]
[1] "A" "C" "B" "D"
```

(the chain is A, B, C, and D, in any order, starting with A and ending in D)

and a chain of length 6 in common:

```
> x[5:10]
[1] "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J"
> y[1:6]
[1] "E" "H" "G" "I" "F" "J"
```

(the chain is E, F, G, H, I, and J in any order, starting with E and ending in J)

I've written the following function to identify subchains of a specific length:

```
subChains <- function(x, y, Len){
    start.x <- rep(NA, length(x))
    start.y <- rep(NA, length(y))
    for (i in 1:(length(x) - Len + 1)) {
        for (j in 1:(length(y) - Len + 1)) {
            canidate.x <- x[i:(i+Len-1)]
            canidate.y <- y[j:(j+Len-1)]
            if (
                    canidate.x[1]==canidate.y[1] & 
                    canidate.x[Len]==canidate.y[Len] &
                    all(canidate.x %in% canidate.y) & 
                    all(canidate.y %in% canidate.x)
                    ){
                start.x[i] <- i
                start.y[i] <- j
            }
        }
    }
    return(na.omit(data.frame(start.x, start.y, Len)))
}
```

Which is used as follows:

```
> subChains(x, y, 4)
  start.x start.y Len
1       1       7   4
```

And the following function can be used to find all chains the 2 vectors have in common:

```
allSubchains <- function(x, y, Lens){
    do.call(rbind, lapply(Lens, function(l) subChains(x, y, l)))
}
```

Which is used as follows:

```
allSubchains(x, y, Lens=1:10)
   start.x start.y Len
1        1       7   1
2        2       9   1
3        3       8   1
4        4      10   1
5        5       1   1
6        6       5   1
7        7       3   1
8        8       2   1
9        9       4   1
10      10       6   1
11       1       7   4
51       5       1   6
```

Of course, both functions are dreadfully slow. Have can I improve them, such that they'll run in a reasonable time on much larger problems? e.g.

```
n <- 100000
a <- 1:n
b <- sample(a, n)
allSubchains(a, b, Lens=50:100)
```

Comment: This really feels like the sort of situation where translating your function to C++ and using Rcpp would probably be the way to go.

Comment: @joran (+1) I've played around a little with Rcpp, but haven't produced anything usable yet.  I'll keep researching this, and will post an update if I produce a workable solution.

Comment: @Arun x and y can get up to about 100,000, and the chain length can get as long as 10,000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would less than a second for your 100,000 case make you happy? Try this:

```
allSubChains <- function(x, y, Lens) {

   N <- length(x)
   x.starts <- 1:N
   y.starts <- match(x, y)   # <-- That's where the money is

   subChains <- function(Len) {
      x.ends <- x.starts + Len - 1L
      y.ends <- y.starts + Len - 1L
      keep   <- which(x.ends <= N & y.ends <= N)
      good   <- keep[x[x.ends[keep]] == y[y.ends[keep]]]
      is.perm <- function(i) all(x[x.starts[i]:x.ends[i]] %in%
                                 y[y.starts[i]:y.ends[i]])
      good    <- Filter(is.perm, good) 
      if (length(good) > 0) data.frame(x.starts[good], y.starts[good], Len)
      else NULL
   }

   do.call(rbind, lapply(Lens, subChains))
}
```

---

Tested here:

```
n <- 100000
a <- 1:n
b <- sample(a, n)
system.time(z <- allSubChains(a, b, Lens=50:100))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.800   0.053   0.848
```

Comment: One question: it seems that your function is checking the start and the end points, but it doesn't seem to be checking that all the elements of the chain are the same. If I run it on my letters example, `allSubChains(x,y,2:10)`, it IDs E, F, G and E, H, G as a subchain.  This is easy to fix, but I thought I'd point it out.

Comment: Ok... sorry about that. I have added a `is.perm` filter. Thankfully, the step that finds subsequences with similar endpoints was selective enough that the `is.perm` check, although expensive, did not affect computation times too much. As it turns out, if I trust the result and my intuition, it is extremely unlikely to find subchains in your large random example: only a handful of them with length 2. Maybe your real data is not a full random permutation?

Comment: @flodel thanks for the update.  You are correct-- subchains greater than a length of 2 are extremely rare.  In the data I'm using, I've found a couple of length 10.  It seems that, in general, I'll be limiting my searches to 2:50.

Comment: @flodel: Your original function is very useful too.  I'll probably end up using both of them.  Thanks a lot!